# Why can $\hbar q_x$ and $\hbar q_y$ be replaced by $\hat{p}_x=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\hat{p}_y=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, graphene, tight-binding

It is written in the book [The Physics of Graphene](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108617567) (Page 10 and 17) that when the intervalley scattering is neglected, we can make the following substitution in the Hamiltonian of the graphene when using the tight-binding model:
$$\hbar q_x\to\hat{p}_x=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
$$\hbar q_y\to\hat{p}_y=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $$
Then the effective Hamiltonian goes from
$$\hat{H}_{\mathit{K},\mathit{K'}}(\vec{q})=\hbar v
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & q_x \mp iq_y\\
q_x \pm iq_y & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
to
$$\hat{H}_{\mathit{K}}=-i\hbar v\vec{\sigma}\nabla$$
$$\hat{H}_{\mathit{K'}}=\hat{H}_{\mathit{K}}^{\text{T}}$$
where $\vec{q}=\vec{k}-\vec{\mathit{K}}$ denotes the relative momentum in the vicinity of the Dirac point $\mathit{K}$; $v=\frac{3a|t|}{2\hbar}$ is the electron velocity at the conical points; $\vec{\sigma} = (\sigma_x, \sigma_y)$ are the pauli matrices and T denotes a transposed matrix.

It hints that it corresponds to the effective mass approximation, or $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{p}$ perturbation theory, however, I still do not get the idea why this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

That substitution can be directly derived from tight-binding approximation. Please refer section 2 of [this article](https://doi.org/10.1143/JPSJ.67.1704), you may find the solution by inserting Eq. (2.1) into (2.2).

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of Hamiltonian near the degeneracy point of graphene is actually the equivalent of the [effective mass approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)) near the band bottom in more traditional materials. In this case one focuses on the long-wavelength component of the Bloch functions (i.e., on the short wave vectors),
$$\psi(\mathbf{r})=e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}u_\mathbf{k}( \mathbf{r}),$$
omitting the factor $u_\mathbf{k}( \mathbf{r})$, which varies quickly on the scale of a unit cell (more precisely, we assume that it is constant). One says sometimes that the effective Hamiltonians obtained by such an expansion are Hamiltonians *for the envelope function* of a wave packet, composed of Bloch waves.

Once $u_\mathbf{k}( \mathbf{r})$ is assumed to be a constant, the relation between a wave function in position and momentum representations becomes a simple Fourier transform, as it is for free particles:
$$
\psi(\mathbf{r})=\int d\mathbf{r}e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}\phi(\mathbf{k}),$$
and hence
$$
-i\hbar\nabla\psi(\mathbf{r})=\int d\mathbf{r}e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}\hbar\mathbf{k}\phi(\mathbf{k}),$$
which is, of course, a basic property of the Fourier transform.